# Object clipping Viewport

Tags: modeling, objects, clipping

I hope you are well. I have a problem that have not before. My object clipping to each other when I zoom out. Objects are not big and have distance with each other. I add images to see my problem.
[[image]

[image]

If someone can help please help me becouse modeling in this situation is hard and my project has stopped.
Thank you.

Comment: This is called Z-fighting. Your character mesh and cloth mesh are so close that blender cannot figure out which mesh is in front. You can either add a solidify modifier on the cloth mesh, or sacle the cloth mesh along normal (alt + S) in edit mode by a small amount

Comment: Thanks for replying. It was clip start. restore it to defualt value and it fixing it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out.
Its about clip start. My defualt clip start was 0.0001 for Edite close objects to camera but when I zoomed out the problem begins.
Restore clip start to **0.1** to Fix it.
Thanks again.